# Как правильно писать сложное условие PHP

Tags: php

Мне иногда приходилось писать, что-то вроде этого (количество сравниваемых операндов может быть гораздо больше):

`if($var1 > $var2 && $var3 < $var4 && $var5 == $var6)`

Корректно так писать с точки зрения тру программирования и как можно данный пример написать компактно? (Если вообще возможно)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно присваивать значения условий переменным, имя которых несет некую смысловую нагрузку.
Составные выражения потом проще читать, когда видишь такое:

```
$isVisible    = $var1 > $var2;
$isAdmin      = $var3 < $var4;
$isAdminPanel = $var5 == $var6;
if ( $isVisible && $isAdmin && $isAdminPanel ) {};
```

Если смысловой нагрузки у выражений нет, то длинные условия удобнее разбивать на несколько строк:

```
if(
    $var1 > $var2 &&
    $var3 < $var4 &&
    $var5 == $var6
    ) {};
```

Comment: ну...а как я писал в вопросе, как все таки правильно писать сложные условия?

Comment: Правильно писать их так, чтобы другой человек, читая Ваш код, не ломал потом голову- что все это означает.

Comment: тогда вопрос исчерпан

Comment: @ReinRaus, еще следует не забывать о группировке условий, а так вы совершенно правы.

Answer (score 3):

Можно присвоить значение условия переменной с говорящим именем

```
$userIsAdmin = $var1 > $var2 && $var3 < $var4 && $var5 == $var6;
if ($userIsAdmin) {}
```

В размере кода не выигрываем, но повышается читаемость - проще вспомнить/понять, что же мы имели в виду данным выражением.

Comment: Круть :) Мы даже переменные примерно одинаково назвали :)

Comment: Про такое дело я в курсе, однако это не совсем то что я хотел увидеть. Ваш пример это присвоение одной переменной результата логических операций между переменными, в последущее использование в конструкции if

Answer (score 1):

Ну я делаю так:

```
if(($var1 > $var2) && ($var3 < $var4) && ($var5 == $var6))
```

тут я думаю у каждого своя фишка.

Comment: если не знать приоритеты операций то можно писать как вы)

Comment: Смысл один, true или false, думаю тут не надо как то выкручиваться ломать голову и т.д)